# How to Add Element to JList in swing?

Tags: java, swing

Hi i am newbie to java and i am trying to add the item from `JComboBox` to the `JList`, but when i run the program, i am getting this error.

How to do this?

error:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : method addElement(java.lang.String)
location: class javax.swing.JList
      openTaskBox.addElement(taskItem);
```

code:

```
public static void addSelectedItemToTaskList(String taskItem)
   {
      openTaskBox.addElement(taskItem);
   }
```

Here openTaskBox is `JList`.

Code:

```
    JList openTaskBox = new JList();
    openTaskBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 50));
    pnlInnerTL.add(openTaskBox);
```

Comment: Is it a `JList` or a `JComboBox`?

Comment: I want to add element to JList

Comment: `openTaskBox` sounds like a `JComboBox` not a `JList`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### For JComboBox

You can use [`JComboBox#addItem(E)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html)

See [How to use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) for more details

### For JList

You have to use the `ListModel`.  [`DefaultListModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) supplies a `addElement` method

See [How to use lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more details

Answer (score 3):

Add the item to the `JList`'s model, not to the `JList` itself.

```
DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel) openTaskBox.getModel();
model.addElement(taskItem);
```

Comment: That, of course, assumes that the model is a `DefaultListModel` ;)

Comment: I assumed so, it seems that OP does not know about models.

Comment: I think from memory, `JList` uses a `DefaultListModel` by default, so you should be safe ;)